# node server stopped running, [nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart

Tags: node.js

**src/app.ts**

```
    async function startServer() {
    const app = express();
    await require('./loaders').default({expressApp: app});
    const httpsServer = https.createServer({
      ca: [
        fs.readFileSync('files/ssl/AAACertificateServices.crt'),
        fs.readFileSync('files/ssl/SectigoRSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt')
      ],
      key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('files/ssl/api.coinexchaPvt.crt')),
      cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('files/ssl/api_coinexcha_com.crt')),
    }, app);

    httpsServer.listen(config.port, () => {
      Logger.info(`
          ################################################
          ️  Server listening on port: ${config.port} ️
          ################################################
        `);
    }).on('error', err => {
      Logger.error(err);
      process.exit(1);
    });

}
startServer();
```

**package.json**

```
 "main": "src/app.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "nodemon",
  }
```

By help of above code i'm able to start a server and server started successfully but after some time. unexpected clean exit occurs and server stop listening.

how to handle clean exit and start listening.

Thanks